# When transforming a list of integers (that contain nans) into dataframes they convert to floats

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a list and I convert it to dataframes I have

```
lista=[1,2,3]
print(pd.DataFrame(lista)
#Got a dataframe of ints
```

but if I have

```
listb=[1,2,3,np.nan]
print(pd.DataFrame(listb)
#Got a dataframe of floats
```

This does not change if I specify `dtype='int64'`

Is there a way that I can get a dataframe with ints?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) for integers with missing values:

```
listb=[1,2,3,np.nan]
print(pd.DataFrame(listb, dtype='Int64'))
    
      0
0     1
1     2
2     3
3  <NA>
```

Comment: You are right. My problem is more complicated.I will ask another question, please take a look